# How to connect an Android device to an FTP server?

Tags: ftp

How to connect an Android device to an FTP server?

Answer (score 2):

As Izzy suggested; did you try an FTP client?

- [AndFTP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andftp&hl=en)
- [Turbo FTP client & SFTP client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=turbo.client&hl=en)
- [FTP Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zifero.ftpclient)
- [WM FTP Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pcsoft.wm_ftp_client&hl=en)
- [Greyhound FTP Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domloge.gftp&hl=en)

I've only used AndFTP before and it worked fine so I can recommend that one.