# How to open FTP URLs on Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, ftp

I can open the following link in Chrome on my PC, but my phone browser, which is also the latest version of Chrome, doesn't open it: ftp://tchdata.eili.ir (can only be accessed from Iran)

How can I open such links on my phone (Huawei P smart, if relevant)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome initially planned to depreciate support for FTP from version 81 but paused it because of COVID-19 (to help hospital staff access FTP resources) . In version 86 (currently latest on Play Store) , support to FTP has been depreciated for 1% users and by Chrome 87, it will be  depreciated  by 50% ([Source](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.zdnet.com/google-amp/article/chrome-87-released-with-fix-for-nat-slipstream-attacks-broader-ftp-deprecation/)).

So if you are lucky (not in the 1%), enable FTP flag by pasting `chrome://flags/#enable-ftp` in the address bar and launching Chrome again by pressing the prompt at bottom right.

Verified with this FTP site ftp://ftp.heanet.ie/   since link in OP can be accessed only from Iran.

If you can't access using browser, see this for other methods
[How to connect an Android device to an FTP server?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/62808/131553)